# Get environment variable from other proccess in Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, rspec

I have the following task: in my C# code I'm running server with random port and adding this port to EnvironmentVarables via

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PORT", Convert.ToString(Fixture.Uri.Port));
```

And after that I have to get this PORT variable from Ruby rspec code to tell tests what port it should use.
Is there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` by default sets target to process. You should use User or Machine target:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PORT", 
                                   Convert.ToString(Fixture.Uri.Port), 
                                   EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx)